# NSString to HEX

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstringencoding

example: NSString *day = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"السبت"];and i think the

representation of this string in hex is this :%C7%E1%D3%C8%CA (windows-1256 encoding)

what i want is how to convert arabic string to hex like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution:

```
NSString *day =@"السبت";
NSData *strData = [day dataUsingEncoding:NSWindowsCP1254StringEncoding];
NSMutableString *mut = [NSMutableString string];
int i;
for (i = 0; i < [strData length]; i++)
{
    [mut appendFormat:@"%%%02X", ((char *)[strData bytes])[i]];
}
```

`mut` will contain the hexadecimal encoded representation of day.

Comment: maybe... we don't have enough info to know how 00-0f should be formatted, if they should be zero padded or not, if so the format should be @"%%%0.2X"

Answer (score 0):

Something like `[day stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:@"whatever"]` ?

Comment: it won't properly escape characters... An other way is to use the CoreFoundation functions, but that's somewhat more complicated. My solution will escape all Arabic characters.